# In the Database (Firebase) with my app after I publish in the google play

Tags: java, android-studio

I publish app in Google Play. 
The app work fine when I install from the android studio or in the emulator.

I have User Object here the user class:

```
public class User {
    public  String name;
    ArrayList<Product> listOfProduct;
    ArrayList<ListForUser> listOfLists;
    public boolean showUserGuide;

    public User(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.listOfProduct = new ArrayList<Product>();
        this.listOfLists= new ArrayList<ListForUser>();
        this.showUserGuide=false;
        firstList();
    }
}
```

Here is the function:

```
public void updateProdToUser(Product p){
    this.listOfProduct.add(p);
}

public void updateListToUser(ListForUser l){
    this.listOfLists.add(l);
}

public void firstList(){
    //tida
    Product p = new Product("Tomato", null, "Choose the most beautiful"); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);
    p = new Product("Cucumbers", null, ""); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("Apple", null, "The most beautiful"); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("Bananas", null, "The most beautiful"); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("lemon", null, ""); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("White onion", null, "The most beautiful"); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("purple Onion", null, "The most beautiful"); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("Green onions", null, "Check the freshness"); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("Carrot", null, "Check the freshness"); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("garlic", null, "Check the freshness"); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("Lettuce", null, "Check the freshness"); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("sweet potato", null, "Check the freshness"); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);


    p = new Product("Milk", null, "Date is the farthest"); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("Cottage", null, "Date is the farthest"); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("Cream cheese", null, "Date is the farthest"); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("Yellow cheese", null, "Date is the farthest"); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("Bulgarian cheese", null, "Date is the farthest"); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("Yogurt", null, "Date is the farthest"); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("Pita bread", null, ""); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("Pasta", null, "Search for an offer"); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("Rice", null, "Search for an offer"); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("Flakes", null, "Search for an offer"); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("Energy bars", null, "Search for an offer"); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("Flour", null, "Search for an offer"); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("mineral water", null, "Large bottles"); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("Olive oil", null, ""); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("Bleach", null, ""); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("Soap", null, ""); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);

    p = new Product("Hair conditioner", null, "Company: Pantene"); // create product
    listOfProduct.add(p);
}
```

That how I push in the Firebase:

```
 String u_id = userInfo.getUid();
 User userInfoermation = new User(fName);

 DatabaseReference dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                                dref.child(u_id).setValue(userInfoermation);
```

And if I do it from the emulator or if I install it from the Android Studio it work fine and it look like that

[image]

And if it from the app I download from Google Play it look like that:

[image]

If you can see the `listOfProduct` don't insert when I use the App from Google Play.

here the firebase rule
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbGO9.png)

Comment: Can you show us your firebase database rules?

Comment: i edit the post with the firebase rule. but i dont think this is the problem because from the andriod studio or the emulator evreything work fine...